# Are there multiple LDTs?

Tags: x86, x86-64, hardware, intel, gdt

The following [Wikibooks page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Global_Descriptor_Table) states:

> The GDT contains pointers to each LDT.

I'm currently learning about segmentation, and this implies that there are multiple LDTs. As far as I can tell there is only one: multiple references I've read refer to "the LDT", implying there is only one. Is the referenced page correct in its implication? Did it mean "LDT entry"?

Comment: It is possible for an OS to designate a separate LDT for each running task or running thread in the system. If using hardware task switching (not recommended because of performance) the CPU will even keep track (save/restore) the LDT on a task switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the [`lgdt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) instruction - used to set up the GDT - takes a `m16&32/64` as an operand - the [`lldt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LLDT.html) instruction takes a `r/m16` operand.

Deciphering the jargon this means that `lgdt` takes a pointer to a structure holding the `GDT` size and base address.
On the other hand, `lldt` take a *segment selector* - this segment selector must have the `TI` (Table indicator) field set to 0 to **point into the `GDT`**.
Long story short the `LDT` is not set up with a base address and a size like the `GDT` but with a segment descriptor in the GDT - so it depends on the `GDT`.

The type of the segment selected by the segment selector given to `lldt` must be of type *LDT* (decimal value 2).

If any of the conditions above fails a #GP is raised.

---

For a given hardware thread and a given point in time, there can be only one `LDT` and one `GDT` active.
The OS can, however, change the active `LDT` or `GDT` (rare) later - based on its own policy (e.g. for specific processes).

However, an OS rarely changes the `GDT` entirely and usually it pre-fill it with all the segment descriptors it needs - including all the necessary `LDT`s.
In any case, the `GDT` can hold multiple `LDT` segment descriptors - but only one is active at any given time, per hardware thread.

Answer (score 3):

The LDTR contains the address of a single active LDT at a time. The GDT can contain entries for multiple LDTs, which are loaded into LDTR one at a time as needed.

Comment: Worth mentioning that mainstream OSes that use paging typically don't actually use separate LDTs. 
 (https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial#What.27s_so_special_about_the_LDT.3F).  The kernel uses the same shared LDT for all tasks so it doesn't have to change it on context switches.